# In how many ways can three gnomes and three elves sit in a row if no gnome sits next to another gnome?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Q)Three gnomes and three elves sit down in a row of six chairs. If no gnome will sit next to another gnome, in how many different ways can the elves and gnomes sit?

I got the answer as 108 as I considered the following scenarios for placement of gnomes. Assume all gnomes & elves are distinct:

```
G_ G _ G _ = 36 
G _ G _ _ G = 36
_ G _ G _ G 36
```

Is the answer correct? If not, please explain what I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: What about G _ _ G _ G ?

Comment: I don't think you should use this type of approach. Suppose I tell you that $10$ gnomes and $10$ elves are to sit in a row of $20$ with the same constraint, then?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal: Good point. Can you please explain how you will solve the case of 20? Is there a shorter way of doing this? Please explain in detail as an answer

Answer (score 3):

There is one more combination as @Peter Woolfitt suggested. More generally you can line up the elves with gaps between them and sit the gnomes in the gaps or in the first and last position and this way no gnomes seat next to each other. Consider the line-up $\mathrm {*E*E*E*}$. You need to choose 3 of the 4 asterisks to replace with gnomes. You can do this in $4 \choose 3$ ways. Gnomes and elves being distinct means that for example G1G2G3 is different than G2G1G3 i.e. you have to consider all permutations for elves and gnomes and thus you multiply by $3!\times 3!$ Obviously this approach can be generalised for any number of elves and gnomes.

Comment: Please explain in more detail. Not sure what you mean by second statement. Thanks

Comment: @SuccessThink Edited for more details as asked.

Comment: But your line up does not consider the possibility GEGEEG?

Comment: It does: $\mathrm{GEGE*EG}$